# vs code-insiders in explorer naming files: waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio-code, key, chord

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
VS code-insiders (code-insiders_1.19.0-1511763384_amd64.deb)
code extensions: (vim 0.10.5)

When trying to create a file or rename an existing file, if I type g, I get a message: (G) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord... If I type j, k, or o or the arrow keys nothing happens.

See an extract of the keybindings file below:

```
{ "key": "left",   "command": "extension.vim_left",  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl" },
{ "key": "right",  "command": "extension.vim_right", "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl" },
{ "key": "up",     "command": "extension.vim_up",    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible" },
{ "key": "down",   "command": "extension.vim_down",  "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible" },
{ "key": "j",      "command": "list.focusDown",      "when": "listFocus" },
{ "key": "k",      "command": "list.focusUp",        "when": "listFocus" },
{ "key": "o",      "command": "list.toggleExpand",   "when": "listFocus" },
{ "key": "g g",    "command": "list.focusFirst",     "when": "listFocus" },
```

The question is: Should the keybindings be active during file naming/renaming in the Explorer window or is this something that I accidently enabled? In the latter case, how do I disable it?